# Derby export and import database securely

Tags: java, database, derby

My aim is to send data from server_1 to server_2 from existing encrypted Derby DB to existing encrypted Derby DB without backup and restore.

The issue is that when I execute

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE
```

The .dat files are not encrypted.

Can I force those files to be encrypted.

Comment: I don't know of any way to get SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE to encrypt those files, but there are other ways to get files on your filesystem to be encrypted. For example, use an encrypted filesystem. Or, run an encryption program on the files after you export them.